# Visual Studio + Crystal Reports + SourceSafe = auto checkout

Tags: .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-sourcesafe

I have a simple VS2008 project with several crystal reports, created with Crystal Reports 2008 (outside Visual Studio). The solution is added to source control (Visual SourceSafe 6.0). Now every time I open the solution all the reports are checked out together with their corresponding cs files. No changes are made to the files, so I can just undo the checkouts, but that's very annoying. Has someone encountered that problem and is there a solution?
Edit: Here is complete description what happens:

- Created several report with Crystal Reports 2008
- Created Visual Studio 2008 solution with just one project and added the existing reports
- Added the solution to SourceSafe and checked in everything
- Closed the solution
- Opened the solution (just it, not the reports) and the reports are checked out with no changes 
  This behavior is not only for me, everyone working on the project has that problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some googling I found [that](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/ebeefa1a-1b30-4075-9c18-6017940a3aa1/) topic in the MSDN forums. My problem is identical with the one discussed there. The solution pointed is updating Crystal Reports. I'm gonna try that when I have time. 
Edit: Yep, it's fixed! :) For anyone with the same problem - just download and install the latest service pack from the Business Objects downloads page.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is'nt a solution to your problem... (I see you've found one) but use another source control system.... it solved A LOT of problems we had (we even had file corruptions with vss). MS is also keeping stuck on 6.0 (don't think any improvements will ever be released).

We made the change a year ago, after another VSS corruption issue, and I my only regret is that we didn't change faster, what a time saver!

I personally use:

- [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)
- [Visual SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) (VS add-in) or use the free [Ankh](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)
- [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

Ask around everybody will tell you that staying with vss is a bad choice...

Just my 2 cents I wanted to give you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually, I have used exactly Subversion with Visual SVN and I know it's better than VSS. It's complicated why we use VSS anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you the reports open in the designer at all?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to narrow down the issue a bit further to see what the issue might be

1. Does this happen with other projects? Perhaps its a VSS issue.
2. Have you tried running a diff on the checked out cs files to see what might have changed? Perhpas VS is running a custom tool on the report files to regenerate the cs files